# Parsing a file and storing data in a list

Tags: python

I have file like this "as.txt"

```
Sr.No.      Name        Enrollment Number   CGPA        Year        
1.          XYZ     1101111             7.1     2014        
2.          ZYX     1101113             8.2     2014        
3.          Abc     1010101             9.1     2014
```

I want to parse this file and store data in a list. I want to extract each row and check its enrollment number, if enrollment no. begins with 11 the save it in secondyearlist else in firstyearlist.

This is what I have tried but I think I am going wrong.

```
import struct

with open("as.txt") as f:
    # skip first two lines (containing header) and split on whitespace
    # this creates a nested list like: [[val1, i1, i2], [val2, i1, i2]]
    lines = [x.split() for x in f.readlines()[2:]
    # use the list to create the dict, using first item as key, last as values
    dict((x[0], x[1:])for x in lines)
f.close()
```

Please help me to do this.

Comment: Why do you think you are going wrong? Share with us what your code is doing, what you expected it to do etc.

Comment: @TimCastelijns: sir I want you to make a list like this when the code is run:
Fourth Year List: [[Hell,1010102, 10.0, 2014, N], [ Abc, 1010101, 9.1, 2014, N]]

Comment: @TimCastelijns: Sir, how can I extract each row and store it in a list

Comment: Add any additional information by editing original question, not by posting it in a comment

Comment: @user3608245 Good you are using `with` for opening a file. But if you use it, you shall not call `f.close() then as the `with` block does exactly this at the moment you leave inner block of it. It is likely, your code is crashing on very last line as you are trying to close already closed file.

Answer (score 2):

## Possible solution

There are many possible solution, this one illustrates few typical constructs

```
fname = "as.txt"
with open(fname) as f:
    # skip first line (containing header)
    header = f.next() #this has just read one line (header)
    print "header", header # just to show, we have read the header line, not really necessary
    # this creates a list of records with each record being: [srno, name, enrolment, cgpa, year]
    records = [line.split() for line in f]
    # initialize resulting lists
    y_11 = []
    y_others = []
    # loop over records
    # we use value unpacking, each element of record is assigned to one variable
    for srno, name, enrolment, cgpa, year in records:
        if enrolment.startswith("11"):
            y_11.append([srno, name, enrolment, float(cgpa), int(year)])
        else:
            y_others.append([srno, name, enrolment, float(cgpa), int(year)])
# note, as we have left the `with` block, the `f.close()` was done automatically
assert f.closed # this assert would raise an exception if the `f.closed` would not be True

# print the results
print "y_11", y_11
print "y_other", y_others
```

## Call it

```
$ python file2lst.py 
header Sr.No.      Name        Enrollment Number   CGPA        Year        

y_11 [['1.', 'XYZ', '1101111', 7.1, 2014], ['2.', 'ZYX', '1101113', 8.2, 2014]]
y_other [['3.', 'Abc', '1010101', 9.1, 2014]]
```

## Few comments

### `f.next()` - reading next line of text

Having a file descriptor, loops are able to iterate over them. So you do not have to call

```
lines = f.readlines()
```

but you can also do:

```
lines = list(f)
```

In all cases, list of lines is returned.

When iterating in a for loop, there is hidden call to iterable using `next()` method:

```
lines = []
for line in f:
    lines.append(line)
```

and again, we have the list of lines populated.

We can achieve the same using `next()` call on the iterable, in our case on open file descriptor.

```
with open(fname) as f:
    lines = []
    line = f.next()
    lines.append(line)
    line = f.next()
    lines.append(line)
    line = f.next()
    lines.append(line)
    line = f.next()
    lines.append(line)
```

We are smart enough to stop just now, otherwise an exception `StopIteration` is raised as soon as we run out of lines in the file. `for` loop automatically catch this exception and stops iterating.

By now we shall understand, how it comes, that with a call `header = f.next()` we got the first line read out. Next time you use `f` in some iteration, it does not return back and follows with next line, never returning the header again.

### Unpacking values into variables

We assume, that `line.split()` returns 5 elements.

We may assign in one step all 5 elements into different variables.

```
record = ["a11", "b22", "c33", "d44", "e55"]
a, b, c, d, e, = record
print a
print b
# etc.
```

In our solution, we use it in `for` loop.

### with context manager automatically calls `close()` on created variable

it is typical idiom to process a file as follows:

```
fname = "something.txt"
with open(fname) as f:
    # process the file

# do not call `f.close()` as it gets closed at the moment inner `with` block is left.
```

This `with` construct using so called "context manager", which is able crating some value by entering the block (on the `with` line) and doing something at the end of it, in our case it calls `close()`

Answer (score 0):

Seems you want the Sr no, I have lists and dicts included.

```
y_10=[]
y_11=[]
with open("as.txt",'r') as f: # no need for f.close() when you use "with open" as the file is autonatically closed
   lines = [x.split() for x in f.readlines()[2:]]
   for line in lines: 
       if line[2].startswith("10"): # check if the 3rd element starts with "10"
           y_10.append(line) # if so add to year 10 list
       else:
           y_11.append(line) # else it starts with "11" so add to year eleven list
print  y_10,y_11
[['3.', 'Abc', '1010101', '9.1', '2014']] [['1.', 'XYZ', '1101111', '7.1', '2014'], ['2.', 'ZYX', '1101113', '8.2', '2014']]

# make dicts using zip, where the first element of each list is the key and the rest are the values
y_10_dict = dict(zip([x[0] for x in y_10], [y[1:] for y in y_10])) #
y_11_dict = dict(zip([x[0] for x in y_11], [y[1:] for y in y_11]))

print  y_10_dict,y_11_dict
{'3.': ['Abc', '1010101', '9.1', '2014']} {'2.': ['ZYX', '1101113', '8.2', '2014'], '1.': ['XYZ', '1101111', '7.1', '2014']}
```

Comment: If you're gonna post only code as answer, it's good practice to explain what it does and how it works

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear how you want to store the variables from the question.

This will read the file, skip the first two lines, and store the data in the 2 dictionaries:

```
fir_y = {} #Sets the variables
sec_y = {}
with open("as.txt") as f: #Opens the file
    raw = f.read().split("\n")[2::] #Reads the file and splits it by newlines
    for v in raw:
        var = v.split(" ")
        if var[2][0:2] == "11": #If enrollment number starts with 11
            sec_y[var[1]] = [var[2],var[3],var[4]]
            #dict[key] = value
        else:
            fir_y[var[1]] = [var[2],var[3],var[4]]


{'Abc': ['1010101', '9.1', '2014']}
{'XYZ': ['1101111', '7.1', '2014'], 'ZYX': ['1101113', '8.2', '2014']}
```

Or, you can store this as a list. It is almost the same, you just use .append():

```
fir_y = []
sec_y = []
with open("as.txt") as f:
    raw = f.read().split("\n")[2::]
    for v in raw:
        var = v.split(" ")
        if var[2][0:2] == "11":
            sec_y.append([var[1],var[2],var[3],var[4]])
        else:
            fir_y.append([var[1],var[2],var[3],var[4]])

[['Abc', '1010101', '9.1', '2014']]
[['XYZ', '1101111', '7.1', '2014'], ['ZYX', '1101113', '8.2', '2014']]
```

Also, when you are opening a file by using "with open("__", "_") as x:" you don't need to close the file after. It closes automatically.